# Grep two words followed by a alphabetic character

Tags: linux

How can i grep "HD" and "SD" both followed by any alphabetic character in one command?

Example: * = alphabetic character

```
dmesg | grep hd* 

dmesg | grep sd*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `-E` option for `grep`:

```
dmesg | grep -E 'HD*|SD*'
```

For your specific example, you don't even need the `-E` option.  Saying:

```
dmesg | grep '[HS]D*'
```

would suffice.

Comment: So it would be dmesg | grep '[HS]D[a-zA-Z]'?

Comment: @user2860658 It wasn't quite clear from your question what you want after `HD` or `SD`.  But if should be an alphabetical character, then you're right.  `grep '[HS]D[a-zA-Z]' ...`